# Are the reported odds to win Lotto Max on https://playalberta.ca/games/lotto-max incorrect?

Tags: probability, distributions, hypergeometric-distribution

The Alberta Lottery displays the odds to win various Lotto Max prizes on their website [here](https://playalberta.ca/games/lotto-max) . Each $5 wager contains 3 sets of 7 numbers. The winning numbers are drawn from a pool of 50, so the probability of any given set of numbers to win should be able to be modeled using a hypergeometric distribution. Therefore, the odds of winning the Jackpot can be calculated in Google sheets using the following formula:

=1/(HYPGEOMDIST(7,7,7,50)*3) = 33,294,800

This lines up with what they report. However, they display the odds of matching 6 out of 7 numbers to be 113,248. Using the following formula in Google sheets:

=1/(HYPGEOMDIST(6,7,7,50)*3) = 110,614

110,614 <> 113,248, so my question is what are the correct odds for this lottery game? I'm not sure if I am making a statistical mistake or if they are...

Comment: Although your *computation* is correct, I believe it is not applicable: this event really means "match 6 out of 7 **but do not meet the criteria for any better prize.**" Thus, you need to analyze the chances of all possible better prizes, too.  As a result, the real answer is likely a bit smaller than your calculation.

Comment: @whuber Thank you so much! So, it wasn't a statistical mistake I was making it was a reading comprehension mistake.

Comment: I wouldn't say reading comprehension: this is a fairly subtle point that wouldn't immediately be evident to most people reading that Web page.  BTW, we can confirm your calculation by noting there are $7$ ways for the drawn numbers to *omit* one of your choices in favor of one of the $50-7-43$ other values. Multiplying by the $3$ selections per wager gives a chance of $3\times 7 \times 43 /\binom{50}{7}=1/110614.$